# GATE ANNIE is not imposing LOOKUP annotation on a keyword present in the gazetteer list

Tags: gate

I am using GATE ANNIE plugin. Sometimes it doesn't impose the lookup annotation on keywords present in the gazetteer list. What can be the reason ?

Comment: Please post some examples (text and not matched keywords), do not request guessing in answers.

Comment: What investigation have you done so far?

Comment: Please provide your example with error description.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's because you have to add the corresponding file.lst of the gazetteer in the file lists.def usually located in: C:\Program Files\GATE_Developer_8.4.1\plugins\ANNIE\resources\gazetteer